# case sensitive string replacement in Python

Tags: python, string, replace

I need to replace a string in case sensitive way. For example

```
abc -> def
Abc -> Def
aBc -> dEf
abC -> deF
```

What can I do this with Python?

Comment: @Mark : wiki uses upper/lower characters for wiki name. I need to replace some wiki names.

Comment: What would be the replacement for 'wSg'?

Comment: It's possible that the answer to the question you asked won't help you with the problem you are trying to solve. What if the before and after have different lengths?

Comment: @Mark : Actually, I'm just replacing strings based on small set of rules, not trying to replace all combinations of possible wiki names. So, wilhelmtell's answer works for my purposes effectively. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from string import maketrans

"Abc".translate(maketrans("abcABC", "defDEF"))
```

Comment: This assumes that the same character doesn't appear twice in the input string.

Comment: This won't work for replacing "foo" with "bar" as the "o" character has to be mapped to either "a" or "r" depending on context.

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on Mark Byers' answer, Here's a solution which works for replacement text of any length. 
The trick is to send a function to [re.sub()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub).

```
import re
def case_sensitive_replace(string, old, new):
    """ replace occurrences of old with new, within string
        replacements will match the case of the text it replaces
    """
    def repl(match):
        current = match.group()
        result = ''
        all_upper=True
        for i,c in enumerate(current):
            if i >= len(new):
                break
            if c.isupper():
                result += new[i].upper()
            else:
                result += new[i].lower()
                all_upper=False
        #append any remaining characters from new
        if all_upper:
            result += new[i+1:].upper()
        else:
            result += new[i+1:].lower()
        return result

    regex = re.compile(re.escape(old), re.I)
    return regex.sub(repl, string)

print case_sensitive_replace("abc Abc aBc abC ABC",'abc','de')
print case_sensitive_replace("abc Abc aBc abC ABC",'abc','def')
print case_sensitive_replace("abc Abc aBc abC ABC",'abc','defg')
```

Result:

```
de De dE de DE
def Def dEf deF DEF
defg Defg dEfg deFg DEFG
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a method using regular expressions. The key point is that when it finds a match it first modifies the replacement string to match the casing of the matched string. This works because `re.sub` can take a function as a replacement instead of just a string.

```
import re

def case_sensitive_replace(s, before, after):
    regex = re.compile(re.escape(before), re.I)
    return regex.sub(lambda x: ''.join(d.upper() if c.isupper() else d.lower()
                                       for c,d in zip(x.group(), after)), s)

test = '''
abc -> def
Abc -> Def
aBc -> dEf
abC -> deF
'''

result = case_sensitive_replace(a, 'abc', 'def')
print(result)
```

Result:

```
def -> def
Def -> Def
dEf -> dEf
deF -> deF
```

Comment: Doesn't work: case_sensitive_replace("aman", "aman", "a man") prints "a ma"

Answer (score 1):

Long time lurker, thought I'd post a suggestion here as some of these seem fairly convoluted.

```
print map(lambda a, b: b.lower() if a.islower() else b.upper(), "aBc", "def")
```

It does assume both strings are the same length, however you could easily replace the lambda with a proper function and check for None on the first input.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient way, and it's very crude, but probably something like this could work:

```
def case_insensitive_replace(string, old, new):
    upper_indices = [idx for idx, char in enumerate(string) if char.isupper()]
    replaced = list(string.lower().replace(old.lower(), new.lower()))
    for idx in upper_indices:
        replaced[idx] = replaced[idx].upper()
    return "".join(replaced)
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that You want to change the second string case according to the first string.
Am i right? So, my solution is the following. String s2 change its case according to the corresponding string s1. The result is storing in s3. One assumption here is the two strings has the same length.

```
s1 = "AaBb"
s2 = "cdef"
s3 = ""
index = 0
length = len(s1)

while(True):
    if s1[index].isupper():
        temp = s2[index].upper()
    else:
        temp = s2[index].lower()
    s3 = s3 + temp
    index +=1
    if index == length:
        break
print s3
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work, although you probably want to add some checks that the string lengths are the same:

```
string1 = "AbcDEFghiJKLmnO"
string2 = "some other text"

string2 = "".join((string2[i].upper() if string1[i].isupper() else string2[i].lower() 
                   for i in range(len(string1))))
```