# Make regex substitution in same case

Tags: python, regex, substitution, python-re

I want to make some substitutions in a text with regular expressions.

```
paterrn= "(ch)|(ce)|(ci)"
replacement_dict= {'ch': 'kh', 'ci': 'si','ce':'se'}
```

The text contains characters in both lower and upper case, hence I use the flag IGNORECASE.

```
re.sub(pattern,lambda m: replacement_dict.get(m.group().lower()),txt,flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

The problem is that now Ch gets replaced kh and not Kh, which I want. I could remove the flag and than insert all the combinations in the dict however, this is not very elegant will be bothersome once I increase the size. Is there a solution where you can make the replacement in the same case as the original. You can assume they will be of the same size.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008992/case-sensitive-string-replacement-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Create a new replacement dict, which contains the capitalized possibilities too

```
>>> replacement_dict= {'ch': 'kh', 'ci': 'si','ce':'se'}
>>> new_replacement_dict= {nk:nv for k,v in replacement_dict.items() for nk,nv in zip((k.capitalize(), k), (v.capitalize(), v.lower()))}
>>> new_replacement_dict
{'Ch': 'Kh', 'ch': 'kh', 'Ci': 'Si', 'ci': 'si', 'Ce': 'Se', 'ce': 'se'}
>>>
>>> re.sub('|'.join(new_replacement_dict), lambda m: new_replacement_dict.get(m.group()), 'Chadci')
'Khadsi'
```