# Python string replacement with a case

Tags: python, regex

I've been writing a python script for *latinizing* a cyrillic text. And there are rules of converting, but before that I have to check the text for exception words and replace them accordingly.

(exceptions.txt)

```
джаз jaz
джек jek
меъёр me’yor
аъён a’yon
пицца pitsa
etc.
```

Here, the splitter is a whitespace

```
exceptions[4].split(' ')[0] -> 'пицца'
```

(cyrillic.txt)

```
Нуқул пИцЦани еявериш зарар.
 МеЪёРИни билиинг!
Мен дЖаЗнИ унчалик эшитмайман
```

The thing is that here the input text is pretty messy and it's purposely.

**Main problem**: I've got to convert the text with a case as in original text where it's possible.

(output.txt)

```
Nuqul pItsani yeyaverish zarar.
 Me’yoRIni biling!
Men jaZnI unchalik eshitmayman
```

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to do? What does your code actually do? [Edit] your question to describe the problem you're having. It helps to include a [mre]. Please take the [tour], and read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: The EASY method would be to read your "exceptions.txt" into a list, and for each original line in the list, and a second entry that capitalizes the input word and its replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008992/case-sensitive-string-replacement-in-python):

```
import re

def case_sensitive_replace(s, before, after):
    regex = re.compile(re.escape(before), re.I)
    return regex.sub(lambda x: ''.join(d.upper() if c.isupper() else d.lower()
                                   for c,d in zip(x.group(), after)), s)
cyrillic = '''Нуқул пИцЦани еявериш зарар.
МеЪёРИни билиинг!
Мен дЖаЗнИ унчалик эшитмайман'''

result = case_sensitive_replace(cyrillic, "пицца", "pitsa")

print(result)
```

Just iterate through all the exceptions:

```
import re

def case_sensitive_replace(s, before, after):
    regex = re.compile(re.escape(before), re.I)
    return regex.sub(lambda x: ''.join(d.upper() if c.isupper() else d.lower()
                                   for c,d in zip(x.group(), after)), s)
cyrillic = '''Нуқул пИцЦани еявериш зарар.
МеЪёРИни билиинг!
Мен дЖаЗнИ унчалик эшитмайман'''

exceptions = '''джаз jaz
джек jek
меъёр me’yor
аъён a’yon
пицца pitsa'''

result = cyrillic
for x in exceptions.split('\n'):
    before = x.split(' ')[0]
    after = x.split(' ')[1]
    result = case_sensitive_replace(result, before, after)

print(result)
```

output:

```
Нуқул pItSaни еявериш зарар.
Me’yOИни билиинг!
Мен jAzнИ унчалик эшитмайман
```